# How to call function having double&

Tags: c++, double

I have read arguments by the following code :

```
int row,col;
double A[maxm][maxn];
double B[maxn];
double N[maxn];

void read_file()
{
    freopen("Dimen.txt","r",stdin);

    scanf("%d",&row);
    scanf("%d",&col);

    freopen("A.txt","r",stdin);
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
       for(int j=0;j<col;j++)
         scanf("%lf",&A[i][j]);

    freopen("B.txt","r",stdin);
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
       scanf("%lf",&A[i][col]);

    freopen("F.txt","r",stdin);
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
        scanf("%lf",&B[i]);

    int value;
    int value_F = simplex(row,col, A,B, value);

}
```

But I have got the error in this line .

```
int value_F = simplex(row,col, A,B, value);
```

The prototype of the simplex function is as following :

```
int simplex(int m, int n, double a[maxm][maxn], double b[maxn], double& ret)
```

How can I call the function simplex ? What is the way ?

Comment: change `int value;` to `double value;`

Comment: 'value' is an int and probably isn't automatically being cast to a reference to a double but that is a shot in the dark.  Please provide the error.

Comment: You're passing an int, instead of a double to simplex.  Cast it, change it or overload the function.  @PiotrSkotnicki is right on the money.

Comment: @MrPickles Casting isn't a good idea as the sizes of int and double are most likely different.

Comment: @KellyS.French actually, the compiler could apply here a floating-integral conversion, but it produces an rvalue, while the function expects a modifiable lvalue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
int value;
int value_F = simplex(row,col, A,B, value);
```

use

```
double value;
// ^^^ a double not an int
int value_F = simplex(row,col, A,B, value);
```

An `int` can be converted to a `double` but not to a `double&`.

Answer (score 2):

`value` is an `int`, but `simplex` wants a reference to a `double`, not to an `int`. Just change the type of `value` to `double` and it will work.